# Open_basedir prevents listing symlink files in php

Tags: php, apache, apache2, symlink

I have a function which returns the current files in a directory. Sometimes it contains symlinks which point outside of my web directory. Unfortunately, when I add a "open_basedir" restriction in my php ini file, the symlinked files are not visible anymore to PHP. 
php.ini file:

```
[PHP]
...
open_basedir="/var/www"
...
```

This is partly understandable because the symlink points to a file outside the allowed directory. But I only need the filename of the symlink itself (not the original file). Why PHP cannot see/list the names of a symlinked file is a mystery for me.
I use this function to get the filelist of a directory:

```
function getFileList($dir)
{
  // array to hold return value
  $retval = array();

  // add trailing slash if missing
  if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

  // open pointer to directory and read list of files
  $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
  while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    // skip hidden files
    if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
    if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
      $retval[] = array(
        "name" => "$dir$entry/",
        "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
        "size" => 0,
        "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
      );
    } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
      $retval[] = array(
        "name" => "$dir$entry",
        "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
        "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
        "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
      );
    }
  }
  $d->close();

  return $retval;
}
```

Should I use another function or is this some kind of glitch in PHP?